# Python: How do I change only one of the variables inside of a list within a list?

Tags: python, list

So I created a list within a list and printed it:

```
a = []
b = []
for i in range(3):
    a.append(0)
for i in range(3):
    b.append(a)
print(b)
```

and the result was:
`[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]` as expected

but when I try assigning the first value of the first list within b with

```
b[0][0] = 1
print(b)
```

the result comes out as: `[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]`

How do I assign 1 to only the first value so I get: `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`?

Comment: You could build your list as `[[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]`

Answer (score 2):

You have three references to the same list (`a`) in `b`. Instead, create three lists. Easiest way is to make a copy of `a` when building `b`:

```
for i in range(3):
    b.append(a[:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three of the same list in `b`. You could remove this dependency by:

```
b = []
for i in range(3):
    b.append([0]*3)   
print b
```